# Height in percentage is not working in any browser (using bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Below I have my code. How to use the height in %

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-" id="t1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
body{
    background-color:aquamarine;
}
#t1{       
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid brown;
}
```

When I use `height:100px;` It works fine but when I use `height:100%;` It doesn't work.

How to give the height in percentage using bootstrap for each div?

[image: mobile portrate]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: If i add in px its working fine. But i want in %

Comment: `%` works as long as the parent element does have a defined height other than the default `height: auto;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding something like `style="min-height: 70vh;`

"vh" stands for viewport height. So, "70vh" means 70% of the viewport height.

Here are a few other ways to control the height using Bootstrap classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: i have use vh but showing different height in mobile view compare to normal view and i have added image

Comment: I think it might be better if you explained what kind of layout you are trying to achieve (along with the code you have so far). Because there might be better ways of doing things.

Comment: I am  trying to build flexible website. Without using height in  % it will not work in mobile view i know this point. so some one sugg what can i do

Comment: I don't know what layout you really want. Also important: Bootstrap is designed for responsive design. What you are trying to do seems to go against that. But I don't really know because I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okie I will explain. I have pasted my code above. If i using px for height it works fine. If i am using in % it is not working.(i.e t1 id). If i am using vh it works fine for normal view. But in portrait mobile view mode the height get increase. I want the same height in both view and i don't want to use @media query for each every mobile view for some of the thing . So i want this height should be in constant

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use `vh` because that is based on the viewport of the device and you look like you are wanting to base this on a parent container. `height` is based on the height of the parent element. When you say `height:100%;` you should think, "100% of what?". That would be the height of the parent.

So give the parent a height in some unit value like `px` or `em` or even `vh`.

Now this can get really tricky at times so reading [the CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) is always recommended.