# How to divide page into two equal parts horizontally using bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am creating two forms in one page. So I need to split page into two halves horizontally using bootstrap4. anyone please help me to do this

I have tried this, but not working

page.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">row1
</div>
<div class="row">row2
  </div>
</div>
```

page.css

```
.row{
    height:50%;
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `viewport height` instead of `percentage`

```css
.row{
    height:50vh;
    background:#eee;
}

.container{
    height: 100vh ;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">row1
</div>
<div class="row">row2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not understanding why percentage will not work and why we need to use viewport height instead of percentage.

Comment: @Nishitha check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363336/6108882

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```
 html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 50%;
}
```